# C++ correcting a memory leak

Tags: c++

Can someone help me figure out how to reuse a piece of allocated memory? The end result of this code should be the use of the same location for the first array initialization as well as the second. Arraysize is const 5.

EDIT: I figured it out. I just needed to use free(nArray); just before the line "nArray = new int[arraySize + 2];" and that allowed me to correct the leak and reuse the same memory location.

```
int main()
{
    cout << endl << endl;
    int* nArray = new int[arraySize];
    cout << "  --->After creating and allocating memory for nArray." << endl;
    cout << "  nArray address is <" << nArray << "> and contains the value " << hex << *nArray << dec << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
    {
        nArray[i] = i*i;
    }
    cout << "  --->After initializing nArray." << endl;
    cout << "  nArray address is <" << nArray << "> and contains the value " << hex << *nArray << dec << endl << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
    {
        cout << "  nArray[" << i << "] = " << nArray[i] << " at address <" << nArray + i << ">" << endl;
    }
    cout << endl << "  --->Before reallocating memory for nArray." << endl;
    cout << "  nArray address is <" << nArray << "> and contains the value " << hex << *nArray << endl;
    nArray = new int[arraySize + 2];
    cout << dec << "  --->After reallocating memory for nArray." << endl;
    cout << "  nArray address is <" << nArray << "> and contains the value " << hex << *nArray << dec << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize + 2; i++)
    {
        nArray[i] = i*i;
    }
    cout << endl << "  --->After reinitializing nArray." << endl;
    cout << "  nArray address is <" << nArray << "> and contains the value " << hex << *nArray << dec << endl << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize + 2; i++)
    {
        cout << "  nArray[" << i << "] = " << nArray[i] << " at address <" << nArray + i << ">" << endl;
    }
    cout << endl << "  --->Getting ready to close down the program." << endl;
    cout << "  nArray address is <" << nArray << "> and contains the value " << hex << *nArray << dec << endl;
    // Wait for user input to close program when debugging.
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The C++ standard gives you no guarantee about "reusing" memory, whatsoever. If you need to reuse a particular chunk of memory you will have to write your own low-level allocator, for your custom container. This is an obvious XY problem. What is the real problem you're trying to solve. No, not the one about using the same memory location, but whatever problem to which you believe the solution is to use the same memory location.

Comment: Try use the vector to manager you array, then use resize.

Comment: regarding your edit: that is absolutely not guaranteed. Just because you `free` what was there doesn't mean that space will be used by the next `new` (also why are you mixing malloc/free and new/delete?)

Comment: Your code shows no sign of using `delete []` anywhere.. Hence leak. If you use `free` on memory allocated with `new`, that is UB.

Comment: Using `free` would be a mistake. Also, please do not edit answers into the question. Answers should be posted in the answer box. Then people can comment and vote on them.

Comment: This program also causes undefined behaviour by outputting uninitialized objects

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do like this. If you want to increase the size of array,  you can create a new array with desired length and the copy everything of old array to new array OR you can simply use vector instead of array.

C++ doesn't guarantee you which memory it is going to use and you haven't deleted the memory where you have allocated at first place, it causes a memory leak.